# bounding of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = n+\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geq 1$. The corresponding function is $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$. Which of the following is true about $a_n$?
A. The sequence is unbounded
B. The sequence is bounded but not convergent

I'm so confused between the two. Can someone please explain which choice is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is unbounded, simply because $a_n \geq n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: thank you so much. You have no idea how much this helps me. Our entire calculus class was debating over it but it makes sense now. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It's a pleasure...!

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example of a bounded but not convergent sequence
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0...
It is bounded between -1 & 2.
However, the terms do not converge to a single number.